# Electron FCM notification onclick open app

Tags: electron, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have integrated FCM from [This Repo](https://github.com/CydeSwype/electron-fcm-demo) and it is working fine.

My question is, I need to open running app when click on push notification popup (App is already open but it's minimized).

Here is notification receive code,

```
ipcRenderer.on(NOTIFICATION_RECEIVED, (_, serverNotificationPayload) => {
    if (serverNotificationPayload.notification.body) {
        let myNotification = new Notification(serverNotificationPayload.notification.title, {
            body: serverNotificationPayload.notification.body
        });
    
        myNotification.onclick = () => {
            // Here have to open app if minimized when click on notification popup.
            console.log('Notification clicked');
        }
    } else {
        // payload has no body.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a message to the main process using `ipcRenderer`.

When the message is received (using `ipcMain`), show your window.

---

Send a message to the main process:

```js
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// ...
    myNotification.onclick = () => {
        // Here have to open app if minimized when click on notification popup.
        ipcRenderer.send('showWindow');
    }
// ...
```

Receive the message in the main process:

```js
ipcMain.on('showWindow', function () {
    window.show();
}
```

[Docs for `ipcMain`.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

[Docs for `ipcRenderer`.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)